# Initializing TinyMCE with contents from database in ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tinymce-4

As Salam o Alikum, I'm working on a .NET MVC web application where i have integrated TinyMCE Editor for post contents, I'm saving html in database correctly and also i can render returned HTML properly on the page but when i set the content of tinyMCE editor it is not initializing anymore and throw an error in console.

> SyntaxError: '' string literal contains an unescaped line break

on this line

```
init_instance_callback: function () { tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc))') },
```

here it is working great.

```
<div class="profile-edit-container fl-wrap block_box">
    @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc))
    @Html.Raw(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc)
</div>
```

It means the HTML in **_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc** is correct.

here is how I'm initializing the tinyMCE editor with contents.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.2.5/tinymce.jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// Initialize your tinyMCE Editor with your preferred options
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    tinymce.init({
        // General options
        selector: 'textarea',
        theme: "modern",
        // Theme options
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons4: "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,

        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "~/css/style.css",
        init_instance_callback: function () { tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc))') },
        setup: function (editor) { editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function (contentEvent) { contentEvent.content = contentEvent.content.replace(/\r\n?\r?\n/g, '<br />'); }) },

    })
});
;
```

I'm stucked that why it is working on sample page and the same not working when i set the contents.
Can anybody help me that where is the issue? Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering that I'm doing pretty well but still not working?, I tried by searching what is un-escaped string and how to escape it than i found that put the single quotes around it, but when i saw in console the error was still there, then i noticed one thing that my HTML is multi-line and single quotes don't work for multi-line string, then i searched and found a way to escape multi-line string by using template literal which is delimited by backticks.

The error was here

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc))')
```

replaced single quotes with template literal as

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(`@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_2TheTable.Models.Post.dsc))`)
```

It works fine now.